# Senha em PDF e Rodapé Personalizado

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

Tenho um arquivo PDF, que é um curso, nossa empresa pretende disponibilizá-lo aos usuários de determinado curso online.

Para isso, tenho que acrescentar senha para abertura do arquivo na máquina da pessoa, e um rodapé personalizado, algo assim:

"Esta cópia está licenciada para Thiago A. Klein, ID de membro: 56789. A cópia, reprodução ou venda são proibidas."

Alguém tem ideia de alguma Gem ou Serviço que faça isso?

Comment: está usando o JasperReports?

Comment: já deu um pontapé inicial? se sim, poderia compartilhar seu progresso? do jeito que está a pergunta está bem ampla, tente explicar um pouco do que já fez ou pensou para ajudar os interessados no assunto a terem uma ideia melhor do que precisa para acertarem na resposta

Comment: A pergunta está mesmo muito vaga. Você quer que o usuário digite a senha no sistema ou no próprio arquivo PDF? Para associar senha a um modelo o Rails tem o helper [has_secure_passport](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Na empresa que estou trabalhando, estamos utilizando esse projeto que converte HTML para PDF: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

Comment: Ainda não tenho nada feito, até porque a dúvida é grande. A senha precisa ser digitada na hora de abrir o pdf na máquina do usuário. O que precisa ser feito é: Quando o usuário pedir para baixar o arquivo, eu tenho que colocar a senha no arquivo e ainda adicionar um texto no rodapé de todas as páginas, como indicado na pergunta. O arquivo .pdf é um arquivo pronto (um ebook, por exemplo), não é gerado pelo sistema. Preciso abrir o arquivo, tamanho aproximado 35mb (!!), fazer as alterações e dar um output com o download/link.

Answer (score 0):

Com uma rápida busca no google, encontrei a gem [Prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) parece resolver o seu problema. Alguma das características dessa gem:

> - Features de segurança, como encriptação e **proteção por senha**;
> - Ferramentas para renderização de conteúdo repetido (i.e. cabeçalhos, rodapés e números de páginas;
> - Suporte a internacionalização;

As instruções de instalação, uso e licença estão no link passado junto com a resposta.